# glDrawElements incorrectly renders points on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, xcode4.3

I am fairly new to OpenGL development on iOS. I'm working on software that will create 3D reconstructions of objects in the form of *.ply files. I'm trying to make an iOS app to visualize these simple vertex-only *.ply files. Everything works as intended on the iPhone and iPad Simulator, but when I run it on my iPhone, the points rendered in the view are glitchy and covered with large squares. Here's the comparison: [iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y7uD.jpg) and [simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m9L7.jpg). Has anyone run into similar issues with OpenGL?

Comment: What kind of primitives are these? GL_POINTS? Maybe you can post the relevant rendering code? Since the iPhone version is showing color, I wonder if it has to do with lighting. Also, if using points, as a test, maybe you can try to render a small data set using triangle strips instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to understand that when running OpenGL ES code on the simulator, you're actually running it on the simulator's software implementation and not on the GPU.

The simulator's implementation is close to, but not identical to the implementation on the device GPU. This means that faulty code may render fine on the simulator. I've experienced it myself on a couple of occasions, like when using glbuffers and not allocating enough storage.

It's obviously hard to say where your code goes wrong, but I'd suggest you to go through your code and look for subtle errors.